# Почему стирают именно бельё?

Tags: выбор-слов

Почему, когда говорят о стирке, стиральных машинах и порошках, обычно употребляется именно слово "бельё". Например: "Пойду развешивать постиранное бельё" (хотя не трусы и майки постираны, а кофты и прочая одежда, не относящаяся к белью). Или: "порошок для цветного белья" (а изображены футболки, платья и штаны). Даже на стиральных машинах подписывают кнопки: тонкое бельё, смешанное бельё (при этом нарисованы схематические картиночки не только с майками и трусами, но и платьями).
Т.е. непонятно почему всю одежду называют бельём, когда речь идет о стирке. Я, например, говорю "стирать бельё", когда речь — о нижнем или постельном. В других случаях говорю "постирать вещи", "постирать одежду" или конкретнее — "стирать джинсы, кофты", и т.д.).

Comment: Вот пример. https://midearussia.ru/articles/kak-sleduet-stirat-vechsi-v-stiralnoy-mashine . И первый же подзаголовок - "Сортировка белья", под которым чуть ниже - "по составу: хлопок и лен... джинсы..." (т.е. джинсы причисляют к белью). Далее в этой же статье: "Кондиционеры. Снимают статическое электричество и смягчают ткань. Благодаря этому вещи меньше мнутся и лучше гладятся. Большинство кондиционеров придают БЕЛЬЮ стойкий приятный аромат." Почему именно белью? Остальным вещам не придают?

Comment: Еще примеры, отсюда: https://www.wonderzine.com/wonderzine/life/life/247187-laundry ."вы и так знаете, что одежду нужно сортировать перед стиркой, а белое бельё — стирать отдельно от цветного и чёрного", "чем больше средства для стирки, тем чище белье".

Comment: Отсюда: https://meduza.io/cards/kak-pravilno-stirat. "Чтобы внутри стиральной машинки не размножались бактерии, разбирать чистое мокрое белье рекомендуют сразу после завершения стирки."

Answer (score 2):

Мне тоже встречались случаи использования слова бельё как собирательного существительного для всех видов предметов стирки - и нижнего белья, и постельного, и столового, и верхней одежды, но только в бытовой обстановке. Видимо, это современная тенденция к экономии средств языка. Нам стало просто лень произносить "развесить бельё и верхнюю одежду", легче сказать "развесить бельё", всё и так понятно. Тем более, что в использовании нижнего белья произошла революция, оно стало частью верхней одежды, особенно летом, когда верхняя одежда больше смахивает на нижнее бельё ))) В нашей современности всё перемешалось: платья стали как нижние сорочки, даже принцесса Диана носила соблазнительные платья-комбинации, это такой тренд, а  когда-то корсеты были неотъемлемой частью женского костюма. Так что можно и не разделять - все тканевые изделия - бельё. Мы как бы вернулись в прошлое. В древности люди носили рубахообразную одежду, которую надевали прямо на тело, она же выполняла функцию верхней одежды. Бельё в современном понимании не было известно и в средние века, хотя тенденция носить под верхним платьем более тонкую одежду уже появилась, в особенности среди высших сословий. Нижняя рубашка была роскошью, которую могли себе позволить только богатые.

На Руси бельём называли изделия из тканей, чаще всего некрашеных, служащих нижней одеждой, а также для разного рода хозяйственных надобностей, его отбеливали. Так что и сейчас люди, произнося слово бельё, имеют в виду все изделия из тканей.

Но это разговорное значение, может, даже просторечие, а в книжных стилях следует, конечно, придерживаться значений, указанных в словарях, например, у Ефремовой:

> БЕЛЬЁ, -я, ср., собир. Предметы нижней одежды, а также тканевые
> изделия для домашних, хозяйственных надобностей. Шелковое,
> хлопчатобумажное б. Носильное, постельное, столовое б. Рыться
> (копаться) в чужом (грязном) белье (также перен.: вникать в
> подробности чужой интимной жизни; разг. неодобр.). II унич. бельишко,
> -а, ср. II прил. бельевой, -ая, -ое. Бельевая ткань. Бельевая веревка (для сушки белья)

Заметим, что бельевая верёвка - для сушки белья, а мы и верхнюю одежду на ней же сушим, может, это отсюда и пошло?

Comment: Людмила, спасибо, исчерпывающий ответ!

Comment: А что ж не приняли его, если исчерпывающий? (галочка под нижней стрелкой)

Answer (score 0):

> Почему стирают именно бельё?

Мне кажется, все довольно просто. Если убрать слово "почему" (а его вообще лучше не использовать, если речь не идет об установлении причинно-следственнной связи), то в вопросе заключен и ответ. Бельё, в отличие от платья (в значении гардероб, верхняя одежда) всегда стирали, независимо от цвета. Оно было тканое, льняное, хлопковое, ситцевое, шелковое... Эти ткани в той или иной степени допускают стирку. Верхнняя одежа была или шерстяной или вообще из нетканых материалов, некоторые исключения - не в счет. Так и пошло, если стирают -- значит бельё.

Да, такого определения ни в одном словаре не найдёшь, тут я не буду спорить с Людмилой, но на мой взгляд оно прекрасно объясняет кажущуюся неправильность.